# Solubility of salt in heavy water vs. "regular" water

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility

I would like to know if salt can be dissolved in heavy water ($\ce{D2O}$) as it would be in normal water ($\ce{H2O}$).

If so, what will the maximum salinity be in $\ce{D2O}$? I know the maximum in $\ce{H2O}$ is about 26% of salt by mass.

Answer (score 5):

Well, consider a salt as $\ce{AB_s}$ in water you have :

$$\ce{AB}_s\rightleftharpoons \ce{A_{aq}^{q+} + B_{aq}^{q-}}$$

And $\Delta H_{s}=-\ce{U +\Delta H_{aq}}$ where $\ce{U}$ is the lattice energy.

When the salt needs to be solvate, $\ce{O-H}$-bonds of water molecules around this salt need to be rearranged. More, the "$\ce{DO}$-bonds" in $\ce{D_2O}$ are stronger than "$\ce{HO}$-bonds".$^1$ Then it will be harder to rearranged hence it will cost more energy to solvate the salt which will be then less soluble in heavy water than in water.

I found [an article](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/je60070a011) in the JACS and as you can see on the image below the maximum solubility of $\ce{KCl}$ in heavy water is a little less than in water (you can make a linear extrapolation) the difference is not quite importante but it looks it exists.

[image: Solubility in water and heavy water too]

Look at the second reference $^2$.

---

$^1$ : https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0706/0706.1355.pdf, p-5

> Nuclear quantum effects are particularly important in the different
>   properties of light (H2O) and heavy water (D2O) where the more restricted atomic vibrations in D2O
>   reduce the negative effect of its van der Waals repulsive core so increasing its overall hydrogen bond 
>   energy.

$^2$ : For the image, http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/je60070a011

Comment: $\ce{O-H}$ bonds in water need to be broken?? If anything, hydrogen bonds are readjusted but no actual bonds are broken in the dissolution of salts …

Comment: I'd say he really mean bond energy especially he does not say  bonds in water broken.

Comment: @Jan I changed I don't know how to say exactly how to explain but there is an intecration during the solvatation of ions.

Comment: This may be far too simplistic but is not that the vibrational zero point energy is smaller in $\ce{D2O}$ compared to water since the  vibrational frequency of $\ce{D2O}$ is $\omega =\sqrt {k\mu} $ where ∗k∗ is the force const, same for $\ce{D2O and H2O} $, and $\mu$ the reduced mass, greater for $\ce{D2O}$  thus the bond dissociation energy is greater.  This would indicate that to solvate with $\ce{D2O}$ by making new bonds to ions need slightly more energy than for water hence lower solubility at same temperature.

Comment: a typo above,, I meant $\omega=\sqrt {k/\mu}$